# How to add a command line switch to a Windows 7 file assocation?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, file-association

I want to add some command line switches when calling a program via File association in Windows 7. This used to be possible in Windows XP, but I can't see how to do it in Windows 7.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/136133/how-do-i-set-advanced-file-associations-in-windows-7
Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in xp you could accomplish this using a registry key, and that probably hasn't changed for Windows 7.  Look for your extension in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.  Unfortunately, I don't remember what the exact modification needs to look like.