# Edit right-click context menus in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, context-menu

I'm looking for a way to edit the right-click context menus in Windows 7. I would prefer to use a graphical editor, as diving into the Windows registry is rather messy, and inconvenient.

If such software doesn't exist, please tell me - then I can start my long visit to the registry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set advanced file associations in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/136133/how-do-i-set-advanced-file-associations-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can taste the following programs:

- [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html)
- [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html)
- [FileMenu Tools](http://download.cnet.com/FileMenu-Tools/3000-2094_4-10810545.html)

Comment: Tried the first two programs, and the (sort of) accomplished what I needed, thanks.

Comment: WARNING: I am surprised anyone would recommend "right click enhancer," as mehper did above. It has the **babylon browser hijacker** hidden in the code! Fortunately my FF 'browser hijack" detection addon stopped it!

Comment: Right Click Enhancer installer version contains babylon browser toolbar but portable version is free of ads. There is also a paid version which didn't contain ads in installer and portable version.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I don't have any experience of such software, but I know there are few. I always use registry directly and prefer to do these kinds of things myself. You could try this one: [Context Menu Editor for Windows 7 & Vista](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/context-menu-editor-for-windows-7-vista-released)

[image]

---

And here's good guide to do this from registry (if you end up doing it):

[How to Clean Up Your Messy Windows Context Menu - How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/)

**NOTE:** Remember to take backup from registry before editing the values.

Comment: This program is only for the context menu on windows folder background when pressing shift and right clicking.

Answer (score 2):

I like [MenuMaid](http://download.cnet.com/MenuMaid/3001-18512_4-75206774.html)

> Are you looking for a fast and easy way to clean up your Window Explorer and Internet Explorer right-click (context) menu? Look no further. MenuMaid makes it simple! Just uncheck the items you don’t want to show up. Restore them at any time.
>
> [image]