# How can I configure the right-click menu in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, right-click

How can I remove/add custom items/shortcuts to the context menu (right-click menu) **by modifying the Windows registry**? I am not looking for a graphical tool like those listed in [Edit right-click context menus in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/209556/edit-right-click-context-menus-in-windows-7), I want to do it myself by changing the registry keys manually.

[image: example context menu]

So:

- How can I do this?
- Where I can find the values that Registry use to make this menu?
- How can I restore the default values if something went wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/209556/edit-right-click-context-menus-in-windows-7

Comment: I don't need graphical solutions,I mean In registry.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to make that a little bit more clear? I understand the distinction between these two questions, but at first glance that's not apparent.

Comment: @nhinkle: post updated , and thanks for the edit.

Comment: We should make this into a wiki.

Comment: @surfasb  : This would be a great idea , if users answer this question adding for each answer a custom item/shortcut to the context menu. This would be a great wiki.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The registry entries you should specifically look at are:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell (for specific file types)
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers (also for specific file types)
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx (for all context menus)
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell (for folders)
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers (also for folders)
```

Remember to always backup your registry before editing it by going to File > Export... in the regedit.exe application.

Or if you prefer to do it using an application (which apparently you don't but I'll put it in here anyway):

You can use [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) and [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shell_menu_view.html) to see a list of all current (and past, as long as the entries have not been removed) context menu items and disable or enable them from there.

*Source:* [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/)

Comment: Instead of just linking to an external source, please [edit] your question to include a summary of the important parts of the guide, and then cite your information with the link as a reference.

Comment: Please See: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1/best-way-to-handle-answers-with-just-links-in-them/1165#1165 and  http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1393/is-it-ok-to-downvote-link-only-or-link-copy-paste-answers/1396#1396

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've edited my answer to add some more info.

Answer (score 2):

If you like to play with REGEDIT ;

Run regedit and navigate to

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers

Here you need to simply delete the keys you don't want.For more see [this](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/context_folders.htm).

But I would prefer small but functional softwares to do this ;

Alternatively you can use an application to edit the items in the context menu.

[ContextEdit](http://download.softpedia.ro/dl/6d151bbd54405babc579aa5f2cc637c8/4818634d/100078704/software/OS%20ENHANCE/cnxtedit.zip) is a good freeware you may want to use. You can also try [ShellMenuView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shmnview.zip). It is a small utility that displays the list of static menu items that appeared in the context menu when you right-click a file/folder on Windows Explorer, and allows you to easily disable unwanted menu items.

[FileMenu Tools](http://www.lopesoft.com/en/) lets you add, delete & customize the context menu items of the Windows Explorer.

It lets configure the following aspects:

- Add some build-in utilities in order to do operations over files and
  folders.
- Add customized commands which let run external applications,
  copy/move to a specific folder or delete specific file types.
- Configure the "Sends to..." submenu.
- Enable/disable the commands    which are added by other applications
  to the context menu and much    more !

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Right Click Enhancer](http://rbsoft.org) instead of messing with registry all by yourself. It can add, remove or edit shortcuts. It also have an option to add shortcuts in sub menu.

Comment: That is ad-ware.

Comment: There is no ads in new version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWE8djm6xno
Ignore the arabic language.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but linking to a video (or a web page/site) is not considered a full answer as the link can change or disappear. Please [edit your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1314280/edit) to include the information from the video here as your post is likely to be downvoted or deleted by the community if it isn't modified. Thanks :)