# right click menu modification non-admin

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, non-admin

I'm not an admin, but I will like to customize the right click menu. 
I searched the web, and fond quiet a few posts on how to change the registry in order to modify the menu - but all require changes in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` wich, as I understood, is out of bounds for normal users. 
What key should I modify? or, what tool can I use?

The OS is windows 7.

Comment: If adding context menu options required access to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` then there would be a ton of programs that exist that wouldn't exist.  You don't mention what these tutorals were exactly.

Comment: To prevent others saying thats a duplicate of for example [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/209556/edit-right-click-context-menus-in-windows-7/209810#209810): Its not. Those tools need admin rights to work properly. So the difficulty in this question is to find a solution which doesn't need admin rights.

Comment: @Ramhound some thing like [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/312042/how-can-i-configure-the-right-click-menu-in-windows-7). all other things I fond on the web are similar.

Comment: @nixda Karan already pointed out while `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is protected its simply a merged view of diferent registry keys.  A normal use has permission to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and WinRAR, WinZip don't require elevated permissions to install.

Comment: @Ramhound Karans answer was posted after my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** key provides a merged view of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`. So as a standard (non-admin) user you should have access to the latter key.