# Customize the right-click menu in Windows?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit right-click context menus in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/209556/edit-right-click-context-menus-in-windows-7)

I want to customize the right-click menu in Windows for specific file types, such as when I right click on image files (PNGs, GIFs, BMPs....) then there would be an option to open the files in a specified program with additional parameters. Can anybody tell me how do it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you could exactly what you want, but you can do some customization by changing the registry settings. See the `Customizing a Shortcut Menu Using Static Verbs` section in this MSDN article: [Creating Shortcut Menu Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If that doesn't allow you to do what you want, you might need to create your own context menu handler, but that would involve programming and if you'd need any information about that I'd suggest looking on [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402379/adding-options-for-your-application-to-the-windows-explorer-context-menu).

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thanks so much for your help!