# Is there a way to add another program to the "Open With" area here?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there a way of changing this part of the "open with" section (not the separate dropdown menu)?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Edit right-click context menus in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/209556/edit-right-click-context-menus-in-windows-7)