# Pass command line arguments to Windows "Open With"

Tags: windows

I have a program that opens with a specific shortcut, but the shortcut seems to send parameters to the application.  If I go directly to the target directory and double-click, it does not work.  However, if I use the command line and pass in a certain argument, the application opens correctly.

I want to open certain file types using the application, but the application must have the parameters, or it will not work.  Is it possible to do this sort of thing?

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I am using Windows 7.

Comment: This has better solutions:
http://superuser.com/questions/136133/how-do-i-set-advanced-file-associations-in-windows-7

Comment: @user309085 Not anymore as of 2023, sadly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Ran into the same problem as @jtpereyda and the solution from @bobbymcr didn't work for me either. I was trying to get all the command line parameters passed into node.js scripts without needing node.exe on the command.

The problem is that if you have already associated the program with the extension via the `Open With` dialog then you will have created an application association, instead of a file extension association, between the two.  And application associations take precedence.

If you don't mind editing the registry you can modify the `(Default)` key at the following path:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\node.exe\shell\open\command`

**You should replace `node.exe` with the application you are adjusting.**

Or you can just delete the application folder from the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications` folder entirely and your `ftype` association will start working.

Be sure to use `%*` which will pass in the remaining unspecified command line arguments or nothing at all.  If you do `"%2" "%3" "%4" "%5"` you will get 5 empty string params passed into your application when you don't specify any command line arguments.

Finally, if you are not ok with modifying the registry by hand then you can use a freeware tool from Nirsoft - FileTypesManager - http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html

File associations will appear at the top of the list, without any text in the first extension column.  Just find the name of the executable in the list and select it to modify the `command line` field for the `open` action name.

On windows7 the changes were reflected immediately without any reboot or application restarts.  However the Nirsoft utility has a feature to "Refresh the Desktop" on any modification, so it leads me to believe that maybe Vista or prior OS versions would cache the data.  In which case the utility would be a better bet, otherwise you might need to log off and log on to see the changes.

Comment: as a note: it seems that the %1 always should be used to pass the associated file to the program. directly using %* seems not to work. At least i got problem with my ".pl" - perl association on my win 7

Comment: I got it to work by trial-and-error, resulting in the following Data value: ```"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "%1"%*``` NOTE: the `%*` value is NOT in quotes, and has no space between it and previous double-quote.

Comment: I also deleted key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ulaw` in the regedit just in case where `.ulaw` is the extension of the files I was doing the procedure for.

Comment: Ho can we pass the arguments (say 'testing') while opening?

Comment: Please change this answer to explictly modify "[HKLM|HKCU]\Software\Classes", depending on the installation context. Don't modify HKCR directly. See the ["important considerations"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-file-types) for file types and the [`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/SysInfo/hkey-classes-root-key) article. It's an understandable misunderstanding given much of Microsoft's own documentation predates the merged view for HKCR that was introduced circa Windows 2000.

Comment: Ultimately the user's choice is stored/cached under the shell's per-user registry key "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts". This key is protected from automated editing, but it can be deleted to force the shell to recacluate the association based on the current settings in the HKCR view.

Comment: In my case, the "open with" association was with not a command line (Windows 7) but with a key value, in my case "ChromeHTML"  (ie not chrome.exe) 
So that required finding where that ChromeHTML was defined - in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command   and there I added my required parameter (in my case --allow-file-access-from-files) to the command.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "%1" --allow-file-access-from-files

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with `assoc` and `ftype` at the command prompt.  Open an **elevated** command prompt and try the following:

```
ftype MyFileType=C:\MyDir\MyProgram.exe /arg1 /arg2 "%1"
assoc .xyz=MyFileType
```

This will associate the `.xyz` extension with `MyProgram.exe` and will pass the command line `/arg1 /arg2 [filename.xyz]` to the program to run it.

Comment: Accepted because this seems to be the right answer from what I have researched.  However, this process seems ineffectual on the system I'm using.  I can use ftype and assoc to verify that the changes went through, but it does not affect the program used to open files.  Maybe the process has changed in Windows 7?

Comment: Using [Marcus Pope's answer](http://superuser.com/a/452550/459230) make it work correctly on my side using Windows 7. Was trying to play `.ulaw` file with `sox` using predefined arguments from it. Note that in addition to delete old application, I also deleted `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ulaw` which was defining the file type.

Comment: CMD's `assoc` and `ftype` are legacy commands. They weren't updated to for the extensions to file associations added in Windows XP, 7, and 8. They only modify the file association and ProgId keys under the system key "HKLM\Software\Classes". They don't read or modify per-user HKCU settings, which take precendence, or the newer subkeys such as "Applications" and "SystemFileAssociations", or per-application capabilities keys from "RegisteredApplications". They also don't read or modify the user's choice under "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts".

Answer (score 4):

The person placing the question reports the Best answer doesn't actually work.

I've figured it out for XP, which might apply to later OS.

At a cmd prompt you need two commands: `assoc`, `ftype`.

These two can show what is associated and then edit the association but there is a twist, the MS instructions seem to be wrong/incomplete. I was alerted to this by noticing an undocumented association style by known veteran applications, why?

This example enables many arguments to be passed to the associate program.

```
ftype name_of_assoc="C\blah\aprog.exe" "%1" "%*"
```

Not a typo that is `"%1" "%*"`. The percent star will not work without the preceeding *percent 1*.

And that goes live immediately, no requirement to log out etc.

Done right will pass 3 to arg[]

```
myfile.wotsit file1 file2 file3
```

Haven't done it but it looks like the following outside quotes would pass -m if the program needs a flag.

```
ftype name_of_assoc="C\blah\aprog.exe" -m "%1" "%*"
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Using quotes around "%*" will have the list of arguments be passed as a single argument. Also, you missed the colon after the drive letter. The correct command should be: ftype name_of_assoc="C:\blah\aprog.exe" -m "%1" %*

Comment: I'm using the excellent FilesTypeMan program, and in this case you need `%1 %*` _without quotes_ !!! damn windows

Answer (score 3):

Not the best solution but the easiest one is using a batch file.

Create a bat file like that and set your default program to it for your file extension. And yes, the empty quote after start is necessary:

{app name}.bat

```
    start "" "{app path}" %1 /edit
```

Example:

BCompareEdit.bat

```
    start "" "C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 4\BCompare.exe" %1 /edit
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me on Windows 10. It helps me to start Word 2013 with the /w option to have a new instance on each launch, which is needed to use Word with virtual desktops.

Comment: For those interested in why the empty pair of quotes `"..."` is needed, see the general `start` syntax here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27265635/6118556

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with an older version of PSP with Windows7

This solution (change the shell\open\command line in the Registry) worked BUT had to have the syntax "C:\MyFolderName\PSP.EXE" %1
NO QUOTES AROUND %1 otherwise this gets interpreted as a constant

Comment: why the downvotes? this answer helped me finally get the command right!

Comment: THANK YOU - I had the quotes and it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://legroom.net/software/openargs) is an extension that seems to do exactly what you want. I've never used it before, but it seems to get good reviews. leave a comment if there are issues.

Answer (score -2):

Make a Windows shortcut and use the following template:

```
"C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe" "c:\data\basejpg.jpg" %1
```

Comment: And how does the user use this to open a file such as ``xyz.jpg``?

Comment: He asked how to change registry to achieve this.