# Console program output not going to stdout when running from file extension

Tags: windows-10, command-line, console

I have a console app, which is supposed to process files with extension `.xyz`, so I associated it with the extension normally, through windows explorer.

My problem is that whenever I do this in a terminal:

`> file.xyz`

instead of getting output to the same terminal, another console window opens with the app, displays its result and closes immediately(you can barely even tell the result).

This doesn't work either `> file.xyz > output.txt`.

(Also, unsure if relevant, but app expects its arguments in the following format: `C:\app.exe" -print -file "%1" %*` which I fixed using [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/361816/pass-command-line-arguments-to-windows-open-with).)

Comment: You said "console app". What do you mean? Did you compile it by yourself?